# Dynamically add singleton methods

Tags: ruby

I want to define the methods a Logger has on a module, and delegate them to a method that returns a Logger.

```
module MyLogger
  def self.logger
    # return a Logger, whatever
  end 

  [:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal] do |_method|
    def self._method *args # WRONG. Want to define something named `_method` for the class
      logger.send _method, *args
    end
  end 
end
```

How do I fix the WRONG line so that this works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
module MyLogger
  def self.logger *args
    # return a Logger, whatever
  end 

  [:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal].each do |_method|
    define_singleton_method _method do |*args|
      logger.send _method, *args
    end
  end

end

p MyLogger.singleton_methods
# => [:logger, :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal]
```

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will help the next poor soul in my shoes!